# select text inside a paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Is it possible to select text or get the position of highlighted text inside a paragraph `<p>` ?

I am showing a text sentence by sentence using a loop of paragraph in vuejs.

```
<p
 class="mreadonly text-left mark-context"
 v-for="line in jsonData.first.segments"
 v-bind:key="line.idx"
 @mouseup="mouseupSel($event)"
 >{{line.text}}</p>
```

The mouseup is what I think is the only possible event I can use, since onselect (@select on vue) doesn't work with paragraph.

What could I do to get an onselect-like event, taking into account that I need the selected text mainly to split the original complete string in two parts?

Should I convert my paragraph into input tags? Is it possible to make them look like paragraphs?

Comment: @Leeish I'm going to test it, but I suppose it creates another annoying issue with the fact that there isn't an event to enable/disable the selection. Tabs don't have onview/onhide events. especially tabs in tabs.

Comment: You're going to want to use [window.getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) inside that mouseup event.

Comment: @Leeish yes it works. The answer is slightly different from that one since we can use \@mouseup. Disregard my comment about onview/onhide. I was thinking about creating the listener globally but I don't need that anymore. (still have issues unrelated to this post tough ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Leeish, here is what I've done. It's a slightly duplicate question apparently, but the answer here might help anyway.

The HTML stay the same, with @mouseup.
On methods I wrote (as quick and dirty example):

```
mouseup(ev){
      console.log('onselect',ev);
      var gs = window.getSelection();
      var data = gs.baseNode.data;
      var data2 = data.substr(gs.anchorOffset+gs.toString().length,data.length);
      var data1 = data.substr(0,gs.anchorOffset) + gs.toString();     
      console.log(data1);
      console.log(data2);
    },
```